# How do I match an entire string to replace it with its components?

Tags: regex, string

OK, so I have been fiddling with this on regexr.com for a long while now and I'm still having no joy.

This is my sample data:

```
<html><body><p>7792,783,5365514 -1,1,-1 6329,46,72141 -1,1,-1 8595,42,49104 -1,1,-1 14386,21,5026 6172,52,128182 6311,51,114826 9108,43,51437 8257,24,7050 5289,55,169099 -1,1,-1 15667,26,8919 29,79,1861956 32,83,2681719 4595,32,16506 8469,22,6113 -1,1,-1 -1,1,-1 -1,1,-1 7912,50,102981 -1,1,-1 6951,15,2579 -1,1,-1 4830,46,70571 6617,24,7553 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 </p></body></html>
```

What I want to do, is replace the entire string with each number. So... I will run the regex once, and replace the string with 7792. then Run it all again and replace with 783. Run it again, replace with 5365514 and so on.

How would I build the first, second and third regex? I can work it out form there...

The numbers are obviously the only parts of this which will change. the rest will stay the same anytime this is run.

Comment: Which language are you running?

Comment: I am using a drupal module. I assume this means PHP? )The module is feeds tamper)

Comment: What about the numbers `5365514 -1` how will this be?

Comment: Those are actually seperated by linebreaks, which do not show up in code form like that but they are there. However if not... (they should be)... I need them to be two seperate numbers.

Comment: Ok, so is the HTML always there?

Comment: Yes it is. I have the possibility of doing this with xpath too... however that seemed to be even harder and I have used regex a little in the past so fest better with this really...

Comment: If you really want (simply) to convert this into a column of numbers (and nothing else) - why not drop "<html><body><p>" and "</p></body></html>", and replace all commata and blanks by linebreaks - in one go?

Comment: I'm storing each value in individual fields. I need to regex it to each field seperately, not have a list of numbers or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have found a suitable answer now. Here is what I am using:

```
<(?:[\s\S]+)>(?:.+?\n){4}(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)\,(-?\d+)[\s\S]*
```

To go to the next line, I simply increment {4} to {5}, and then I get three capture groups for that line: $1 $2 and $3. This feels like a far better solution than before (and actually fits inside the box I need to enter it into, which I didn't realise until after posting my previous answer that was too long).

http://regexr.com/3a0e3

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I have finally worked out A solution though it is clearly not the best. I am still wondering if anyone has a better option than this, but posting this so that it might be useful out there somewhere?

This is my regex:

```
<(?:[\s\S]+)>-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s-?(\d+)\,-?(\d+)\s.*
```

I then have 125 groups to use to replace with as I see fit for my purpose. :) It works in Regexr here: http://regexr.com/3a0cm

Answer (score 0):

here is your 125 matches using this pattern

```
(?:<html><body><p>|\G[, ])\K(-?\d+)(?=.*<\/p><\/body><\/html>$)
```

http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/146

Comment: The problem with this is it wasn't matching the whole string, so replacing it wouldn't have worked how I wanted it to.

Comment: what do you mean? would you elaborate some more?

Answer (score 0):

I would strip the html (s/<[^>]*>//g), then replace the commas and spaces with newlines, then explode() the string on newline.  The result would be an array of all the numbers in the string.